# Click on a childnode's child and the lines disappear - Primefaces 3.4 mindmap

Tags: java, primefaces, mindmapping

The problem is as stated above, essentially. While in the example here:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/mindmap.jsf

if you click on NS(s) you can click on one of the childnodes of your choice, say, ns7.google.com, and then go back to NS(s) as the line which joins them remains.

I have 6 entries, say 1,2,3,4,5,6. They are all linked in various ways, which are shown by colour in the mindmap. Say "1" is the rootnode. Then 2,3,4,5,6 show up. Say I click 6 - the mindmap is redrawn to show the links of 6, with 1 up away in the corner to show it's the root. However, if I click on any node other than 1 from there, the linking lines all disappear, as do most of the nodes (I don't know why sometimes it's some of them and sometimes different ones and sometimes one and sometimes all!) and I can no longer go backwards. Below is the code for the mindmap bean and the html:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jsf;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import jpa.entities.Enginetable;
import jpa.session.EnginetableFacade;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.mindmap.DefaultMindmapNode;
import org.primefaces.model.mindmap.MindmapNode;

/**
 *
 * @author AOL
 */
@Named(value = "mmBean")
@RequestScoped
public class mmBean implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private jpa.session.EnginetableFacade ejbFacade;
    private MindmapNode root;

    private MindmapNode selectedNode;

    private List<Enginetable> elements;
    private List<Enginetable> filteredElements;
    private List<Enginetable> userlist;

    private Enginetable selectedElement;
    private Enginetable[] selectedElements; 


    private List<Enginetable> elementlist = new ArrayList<Enginetable>();

    private Enginetable nodeentity = new Enginetable();
    private Enginetable rootentity = new Enginetable();
    private Enginetable user = new Enginetable();

    private static final String[] username;

    static{

        username = new String[10];  
        username[0] = "Mercedes";  
        username[1] = "BMW";  
        username[2] = "Volvo";  
        username[3] = "Audi";  
        username[4] = "Renault";  
        username[5] = "Opel";  
        username[6] = "Volkswagen";  
        username[7] = "Chrysler";  
        username[8] = "Ferrari";  
        username[9] = "Ford";  
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of MmBean
     */
    public mmBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ///if(elements==null){
        elements = new ArrayList<Enginetable>(); 
        this.userlist = this.getFullList();
        Enginetable entity;
        //} 
        //remoteuser=null;
        // this.populateRandomElements(elements, 10); 
        this.populateRandomElements(elements,6);  

        // filteredElements = new ArrayList<Graphelement>();
        this.user = this.userlist.get(0);
        this.rootentity = this.user;
        root = new DefaultMindmapNode(user.getStartnode(), "Google", "006666", false);
        /*MindmapNode bmw = new DefaultMindmapNode("BMW", "IP Nos", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode volvo = new DefaultMindmapNode("Volvo", "Names", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode audi = new DefaultMindmapNode("Audi", "Malicious ", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode renault = new DefaultMindmapNode("Renault", "IP Nos", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode opel = new DefaultMindmapNode("Opel", "Names", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode volkwagen = new DefaultMindmapNode("Volkswagen", "Malicious ", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode chrysler = new DefaultMindmapNode("Chrysler", "IP Nos", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode ferrari = new DefaultMindmapNode("Ferrari", "Names", "6e9ebf", true);
        MindmapNode ford = new DefaultMindmapNode("Ford", "Malicious ", "6e9ebf", true);*/


        Object label = root.getLabel();


        for( int i = 0 ; i < this.userlist.size() ; i++){

                    entity = this.userlist.get(i);


                    if ( !label.equals(entity.getStartnode() ) && this.user.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode() ) )  { ////this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())

                            root.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "33FF00", true));

                    } 

                    else if ( !label.equals(entity.getStartnode() ) && this.user.getEndnode() != entity.getStartnode() ){

                            root.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "CC0000", true));

                    }

        }

    }

    public void setElements(List<Enginetable> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public List<Enginetable> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
    public void setFilteredElements(List<Enginetable> filteredElements) {
        //this.filteredElements = filteredElements;
        this.elements=filteredElements;
    }

    public List<Enginetable> getFilteredElements() {
        return filteredElements;
    }

    public void setSelectedElements(Enginetable[] selectedElements) {
        this.selectedElements = selectedElements;
    }

    public Enginetable[] getSelectedElements() {
        return selectedElements;
    }

    public void setSelectedElement(Enginetable selectedElement) {
        this.selectedElement = selectedElement;
    }

    public Enginetable getSelectedElement() {
        return selectedElement;
    }

    public MindmapNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public MindmapNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }
    public void setSelectedNode(MindmapNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }



    public void onNodeSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        MindmapNode node = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();


            for( int i = 0 ; i < this.elements.size() ; i++){
                    Enginetable entity;
                    Object label = node.getLabel();
                    Object rootlabel = this.root.getLabel();

                    entity = userlist.get(i);

                    if ( entity.getStartnode() == rootlabel ){
                        this.rootentity = entity;
                    }
                    if ( entity.getStartnode() == label ){
                        this.nodeentity = entity;
                    }

            }
    //load children of select node and add via node.addNode(childNode);
    //populate if not already loaded
            if(node.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
               this.setChildNodes( node ); 
            }
        }


    public void onNodeDblselect(SelectEvent event) {
        this.selectedNode = (MindmapNode) event.getObject();        
    }


    private EnginetableFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }



    private void populateRandomElements(List<Enginetable> list, int size) { 
        userlist = this.getFullList();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)  {

                Enginetable gel = new Enginetable();
                gel.setMoveid(i);
                gel.setUserid(i);
                gel.setStartnode(username[i]);
                gel.setEndnode(username[9-i]);
                gel.setConnections(username[9-i]);
         //       gel.setPurpose("dubious");
         //       gel.setRelationship("naughty");
         //       gel.setExperimentid(1);
                gel.setNewinfovalue(1);
                gel.setNewconnectioncost(1);
                list.add(gel);                
        }
    }

//


    public Integer getMoveId(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getMoveid();
    }

    public void setMoveId(Enginetable ent, Integer id) {
        ent.setMoveid(id);
    }

    public Integer getUserId(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getMoveid();
    }

    public void setUserId(Enginetable ent, Integer id) {
        ent.setMoveid(id);
    }

    public String getStartNode(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getStartnode();
    }

    public void setStartNode(Enginetable ent, String startnode) {
        ent.setStartnode(startnode);
    }

    public String getEndNode(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getEndnode();
    }

    public void setEndNode(Enginetable ent, String endnode) {
        ent.setEndnode(endnode);
    }

 /*   public int getExperimentid(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getExperimentid();
    }

    public void setExperimentid(Enginetable ent, int experimentid) {
        ent.setExperimentid(experimentid); 
    }*/

    public int getNewInfoValue(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getNewinfovalue();
    }

    public void setNewInfoValue(Enginetable ent, int totalinfovalue) {
        ent.setNewinfovalue(totalinfovalue);
    }

    public String getConnections(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getConnections();
    }

    public void setConnections(Enginetable ent, String connections) {
        ent.setConnections(connections);
    }

    public String getNewConnections(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getConnections();
    }

    public void setNewConnections(Enginetable ent, String newconnections) {
        ent.setConnections( newconnections );
    }

 /*   public String getUserName(Enginetable ent) {
        return ent.getUsername();
    }

    public void setUsername(Enginetable ent, String name) {
        ent.setUsername(name);
    }
 */

    // ADDED BY AODHÁN

    public List<Enginetable> getListByUsername(String user){
       return this.ejbFacade.getEnginetableByUsername(user);
    } 

    public List<Enginetable> getListByUserID( int id ){
       return this.ejbFacade.getEnginetableByUserid(id);
    } 

    public List<Enginetable> getFullList(){
       return this.ejbFacade.getFullEnginetable();
    } 

    public void setChildNodes( MindmapNode node ){

            for( int i = 0 ; i < this.userlist.size() ; i++){
                    Enginetable entity;

                    entity = this.userlist.get(i);

                    if ( (this.nodeentity.getStartnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getStartnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) && (this.nodeentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) &&  (this.rootentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() == null : this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode()))  )  {

                            node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "33FF00"));

                    } 

                     else if ( (this.nodeentity.getStartnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getStartnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) && (this.nodeentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() == null : this.nodeentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) &&  (this.rootentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() == null : this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode()))  )  {

                            node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "0066FF"));

                    }

                    else if ( (this.nodeentity.getStartnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getStartnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) && (this.nodeentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() == null : this.nodeentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) &&  (this.rootentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode()))  )  {

                            node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "FFCC00"));

                    }

                    else if ( (this.nodeentity.getStartnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getStartnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) && (this.nodeentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.nodeentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode())) &&  (this.rootentity.getEndnode() == null ? entity.getStartnode() != null : !this.rootentity.getEndnode().equals(entity.getStartnode()))  )  {

                            node.addNode(new DefaultMindmapNode(entity.getStartnode() , "Malicious Software: ", "CC0000"));

                    }

                }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<h:form>
    <p:mindmap value="#{mmBean.root}" style="width:100%;height:600px">
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{mmBean.onNodeSelect}" />
        <p:ajax event="dblselect" listener="#{mmBean.onNodeDblselect}" update="output" oncomplete="details.show()"/>
    </p:mindmap>    

    <p:dialog widgetVar="details" header="Node Details" resizable="false" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
        <h:outputText id="output" value="#{mmBean.selectedNode.data}" />
    </p:dialog>                 
</h:form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem and eliminated it by simply adding `@SessionScoped` instead of `@RequestScoped`.

Now I can select and doubleselect as shown in the example of PF.